# boost1.62 socket broken after reconnect in docker container

Tags: c++, docker, boost-asio

we have a c++ Application with boost1.62 and libssl1.0, that opens a TLS connection to a lighttpd Webserver (remote).

This works fine on any device we already rolled out. Now we are trying to use this application inside a container. The application starts up and everything is fine but.

When the connection gets reset for any reason, the application attempts to reconnect by making a new TCP-Connection with the socket.

Creating a HTTPS-Connection with TLS over that socket fails with EOF. Then the application tries to reconnect and gets the same fault -> endless reconnection loop.

I recorded the traffic and have seen the following:

1. Everything is alright
2. A TLS-Alert is recorded, sometimes also a TCP RESET.
3. Client sends SYN
4. Server sends SYN ACK
5. Client sends ACK
6. Client sends FIN, ACK
7. Server sends ACK
8. Server sends FIN, ACK
9. Client sends ACK

Steps 3 to 7 occur in less than 3 ms.
as soon as Step 7 has passed, a new connection is made starting with step 3.

I'm using an ubuntu 18.04 on host and as base image. (Both x64)
Both host and container use the same libraries. Therefore i think its not an issue with used libraries.

The application runs in production for over a year on several arm32v7 and x64 devices. This error never occurred then.

Oddly, if the application is configured to use plain HTTP instead HTTPS, the error does not occur.

Any suggestions what this might be? Based on my knowledge i can rule out the following:

- wrong dependencies
- misconfigured Kernel (container and host use the same)

Thanks for your help

Comment: Sounds like you found a bug in your program. Unfortunately I would not be able to give any hints without having access to relevant parts of the program code. What you could do is attach a debugger while the program is running (or restart it inside a debugger) to analyse why it happens.

Comment: Yeah as hard as it usually is, try to reproduce the problem with code only the necessary boost asio calls, so we can try to reproduce it. If it still occurs with that, you have something you can bother the ubuntu, network driver, docker or boost people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a disconnect, we reused the old socket. This works flawless outside docker. Inside docker it produces the described behaviour.

Workaround: delete the broken socket and create a new one.

This is bad for performance though.